# MS Access 2010 Form filter doesn't work with last year

Tags: database, forms, date, ms-access, filter

I have a form in which I have a subform linked to a table that contains various columns and rows, one of which is a Date Created column.
In this form there is a button that filters the subform so that it shows all records starting from half a year ago, here is the code for the variable

```
startDate_S = Replace(Format(DateAdd("m", -6, Date), "mm/dd/yyyy"), ".", "/")
```

And the filter itself

```
ProbSub.Form.Filter = "[Date Created] > #" & startDate_S & "#"
```

The DateAdd() sets the current date back by 6 months, Format() and Replace() change the date format to the american one instead of the local one (MS Access filters only use this standard).
I use a messagebox to see that the formatting is correct, it returns "12/06/2015".
But it does not return any of the rows (I have 3 with the Date Created values of "06/03/2016"). Through debugging I have found that this occurs only when the starting date is a year ago or later, e.g., when startDate_S is "01/01/2016" or higher it works, but when it is "12/31/2015" or lower it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is need for Replace:

```
startDate_S = Format(DateAdd("m", -6, Date), "mm\/dd\/yyyy")
```

Your filter should work if `[Date Created]` is of data type Date, but not if is Text. If so:

```
ProbSub.Form.Filter = "DateValue([Date Created]) > #" & startDate_S & "#"
```

Comment: Yes! The "Date Created" was in fact a text field due to the format in which it had to be. Using DateValue() to convert it in the filter worked perfectly!

Comment: As you see, you should _always_ store dates as Date. It's a value of no format. A format is needed only for display or when concatenating the value with text.